# org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JBossWebRealm Error during authenticate java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, jboss, security, jboss5.x

I got below exception when I try to restart my server.

```
2012-06-07 17:46:14,872 ERROR [http-0.0.0.0-8080-25]-[org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JBossWebRealm] Error during authenticate
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.JBossAuthorizationManager.getRolesAsSet(JBossAuthorizationManager.java:317)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.JBossAuthorizationManager.getUserRoles(JBossAuthorizationManager.java:233)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.auth.JaasSecurityManagerBase.getUserRoles(JaasSecurityManagerBase.java:457)
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.JaasSecurityManager.getUserRoles(JaasSecurityManager.java:208)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JBossWebRealm.getCachingPrincipal(JBossWebRealm.java:669)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:181)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

---

The code of method getRolesAsSet in JBossAuthorizationManager of JBOSS as below:
//Private Methods

```
private HashSet<Principal> getRolesAsSet(RoleGroup roles)
    {
       HashSet<Principal> userRoles = null;
       if( roles != null )
       {
          userRoles = new HashSet<Principal>();
          List<Role> rolesList = roles.getRoles();
          for(Role r: rolesList)
          {
             userRoles.add(new SimplePrincipal(r.getRoleName()));
          } 
       }
       return userRoles;
    }
```

As I known (and already did some simple tests on the method), if there are some threads do adding or removing Role of the RoleGroup "roles" at the same time iterator over roleList is called, we will get ConcurrentModificationException as above.

I think this a bug of JBOSS. Not sure if we can do some configuration in JBOSS to avoid this.
My JBOSS server version is "jboss-5.1.0.GA"

Please give me some advices. Thanks.

Comment: The root cause is memory address reference problem. Hence I decided to patch JBOSS for my application by create a new memory address for the variable role list. Something like this:
          List<Role> rolesList = new ArrayList<Role>();
          rolesList.addAll(roles.getRoles());
          for(Role r: rolesList)